# Google Instant Keyboard Navigation stopped working

Tags: google-search

I just noticed that the keyboard navigation stopped working for me in Google Chrome. I tried to re-activate Google Instant and to re-login, but that didn't solve it. How can I reactivate it? Or do you experience the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after you perform a search.](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/09/googles-new-search-interface-removes.html)

Comment: But that's new, right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. The article I linked to was published September 2011.